# Gentoo Linux: Enabling a mbeq equalizer for ALSA breaks application audio but works when tested with speaker-test

Tags: gentoo, alsa

I am running Gentoo Linux using kernel Linux-4.3.3-hardened-r4 and my sound system is only ALSA, i.e. no OSS or Pulseaudio. I am trying to enable a system-wide equalizer, but since `alsaequal` never worked on my computer and the fix involves tinkering with the source code, I am using the `mbeq` plugin. I performed the steps described [on this unofficial Gentoo wiki](http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/HOWTO_Set_up_a_system-wide_equaliser_with_ALSA_and_LADSPA), and I can get the audio to play through the equalizer using `speaker-test -D plug:eq -c 2` (and I know it works because the timbre of the white noise output is notoriously different from what I listen using `speaker-test -D plug:dmix -c 2`).

However, when I try to play audio using an user app like an HTML5 YouTube video on Firefox or a song on Audacious, I get no sound.

This is what I pasted on `/etc/asound.conf`:

```
pcm.eq {
    type ladspa
    slave.pcm "plug:dmix"

    plugins [
    {   
        label mbeq
        id 1197
        input {
            # The following setting is just an example, edit to your own taste:
            # bands: 50hz, 100hz, 156hz, 220hz, 311hz, 440hz, 622hz, 880hz, 1250hz, 1750hz, 25000hz,
            # 50000hz, 10000hz, 20000hz
            controls [ -5 -5 -5 -5 -5 -10 -20 -15 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -3 -2 ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "eq"
}

# Redirect the OSS emulation through the EQ too (when programs are running through "aoss")
pcm.dsp0 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "eq"
}
```

Comment: I had a similar experience today. On a raspberry pi 3, b+. Running latest Raspbian. My asound.conf looked similar to yours. I could play audio fine using aplay, it sounded lovely and mbeq is obviously a much more competent EQ than alsaequal. However, playing audio from the applications pertinent to my setup, MPD and shairport-sync, would result in static coming through the speakers. I looked at the stream info, and as far as I could tell there was no difference in the data provided by aplay compared to the other applications. Sampling rate, bit depth etc, all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with sending sound from applications like web browser, and they are set to alsamixer straight, where other audio player like vlc, is settings automatic to output set in the system automatically.

I had that issue when I could not play sound and in applications but Youtube from web was playing fine.  I need switch sound cart in side of application, rather playing in alsamixer..

Linux with sound have always complicated thinking about sending sound to sound card. Never was easy, And i think they should do easy, because windows made that and no one never have problem with correct settings and playing sound from different players. Linux Always have problem, and is not user friendly in all distributions.